# Do compressed images improve canvas performance

Tags: html, image, canvas, compression, image-compression

I was wondering, does compressing an image (jpg, png) improve the performance of an web application based on html5 canvas, or does it only improve user experience becasue the load time it less.

Comment: I would say no--compressed images **do not** improve canvas performance noticeably.  Canvas draws images so fast that canvas is probably not going to be a bottle-neck (except **sometimes** in mobile).  After that it comes down to the usual large-quality-image versus smaller-quicker-download-image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do forgot to mention that i am searchin for optimization for mobile indeed. But for what i can get out of your reply isn't that where i shoud focus on :)

Answer (score 0):

It improves loading time and consumes less space in the cache, but doesn't directly impact canvas performance.

Images must be decompressed and converted to the right pixel format before they can be used on canvas, so after the decompression is done (once), it doesn't make a difference.